# _Layout.cshtml in MVC3 with Razor has view mode?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need some help!
I try to design my master page by _Layout.html with Razor. But I can see it as review cause there's no View mode in Visual Studio. I just want to know: Does _Layout.cshtml in MVC3 has view mode, source mode and split mode like masterpage (*.Master) ? If yes, how can I use it? 
Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, there is currently no WYSIWYG editor in Visual Studio for ASP.NET MVC view designing.

***But*** there is a brighter side to that answer.  Use FireFox and a plug-in called Firebug.  Firebug is possibly one of the greatest tools that a web developer can have.  It not only lets you see everything from markup to Ajax requests, but it also allows you to do real-time editing/modifying of HTML and CSS.

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/downloads)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Shark. Glad to hear from you. :D

Comment: @AbigailVo Glad to help.  See my edit.  Firebug is going to be your best friend. :)